# returning a variable javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

```
(function(){
    createCanvas('someid', 150, 150);

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#09f';    // ctx is not defined
}) ();

function createCanvas(canvasid, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = canvasid;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    var ctx = document.getElementById(canvasid).getContext('2d');
    return ctx;
}
```

I am trying to return ctx from the function that creates the canvas, however I am getting the error ctx is not defined.

Is there a way to return this variable from the createCanvas function? Or should I create the ctx variable in the first function?

Comment: You can learn more about functions by having a look at this JavaScript tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning but not using it.

```
(function(){
    var ctx = createCanvas('someid', 150, 150); // now ctx is defined
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#09f';    
})();
```

You need to assign the return value to a variable so you can use it. If you want, you can also use it like this, if you don't have any further use of that variable.

```
createCanvas('someid', 150, 150).strokeStyle = '#o9f';
```